# Views not displaying in the location as in the storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Am working on an iPad App. I have a view with 3 parts. The top part is where I display the date (it's a thin strip). The second and third parts (which are a UIView each) have been added inside a scroll view like this

[image]

I have set the scroll view size thus in Storyboard in XCode :

[image]

Now, in code, I have set the content size of the scroll view to :

```
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768.0, 1500.0)];
```

in viewDidLoad()

The views within the scroll view have these frame parameters set in storyboard :

VIEW 1

This view displays 3 pie charts

[image]

[image]

Then below this view I have view 2.

VIEW 2

[image]

whose frame is set in storyboard as :

[image]

**THE ISSUE**
Now, when I run the App, am not seeing view 1 (the pie charts at all). View 2's content is being displayed in the whole page (it scrolls beyond the page also) as if View 1 was never there.
However, if in storyboard, I set the frame size of the scroll view to 1000 (height), View 1 is seen, then the rest of the page is blank, and then if I scroll (after the huge blank space) I see view 2's content.

Why is it that, even though I have set the frame parameters right in storyboard, the views are not appearing one after another when the App is run?

What am I missing here? Please help.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To me it doesn't look like your autosizing is set up correctly at all...

To get the result you are describing, I believe you need to set your autosizing to the following values:

scrollview - Anchor to all sides(top, bottom, left, and right) and stretch vertically and horizontally.

view1 - Anchor to top and left, no stretching.

view2 - Anchor to top and left, no stretching.

Try setting those values and see if you get a result closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @darkfoxmrd , Thanks for your reply. I tried it, but still the same. I played around quite some time with the anchors and stretch factors, in vain. The View2 is a UITableView, and so it's a UIScrollView in itself. And since View1 is a chart which is fixed in size and view2 has a scrollbar within it already, so I set the content size of the overall scrollview as fixed. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, and now I think I understand the situation more, please see my edited answer, and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi @darkfoxmrd, thanks for your reply. The same issue persists. Lot of whitespace (half a page height of white space) between view1 and view2 :( !